# How to have a normal bar by Bootstrap? (Not a Navigation)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a bar on the top of my site, its not a navigation bar. Various items will go on this bar. So I was thinking How can use Bootstrap for this purpose. There is a nav bar in Bootstrap but I used it already for the navigation of my bar. Can I also use it for different purposes?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navbar-static-top` instead of `navbar-fixed-top` for your Bootstrap's Navigation bar.

Add `<div id="normal-bar">My normal bar</div>` before your Bootstrap's Navigation bar and you can customize it any way you want.

Bootstrap's Starter template - **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/9lZqV5v267)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="normal-bar">My normal bar</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
......
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding-top: 0px; /* It was 50px before */
}
#normal-bar {
  /* Your CSS - It's only for DEMO */
  background-color:#f00;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 0px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `nav`. For additional bars and sections use this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Some text here or whatever you want</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `nav` has `position:fixed` and `min-height:50px` properties, so don't forget to add to your next section `margin-top:50px` so it's visible.

Comment: There's no need to use the `navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: Thank you so much, it wasnt 100% what i wanted but really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use two navigation bars to achieve this behavior by using two separate navbars with `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar-static-top`. See [this example](http://www.bootply.com/101069#) on bootply.